# algorithm behind taveling sites

Tags: java, c++, graph

Can any one please let me know the algorithms that is used in traveling sites like makemytrip.com,cleartrip.com etc.. i know that its a graph problem and they calculate spanning tree..but i want a clear algorithm and different complexities involved in designing the algorithm.

can u please any url references where i could learn solving the graph based problems.

Comment: These sites probably don't use an MST, since MSTs do not guarantee shortest paths between all points.  But an interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: Last I heard, http://www.itasoftware.com/ had a gigantic LISP system that is nearly magical; all sites just call into the ITA backend and slap their own interface on the results. Microsoft bought one of their clients, Google bought them. Go figure. :)

Answer (score 1):

Travelling sites wouldn't use minimum spanning trees but would usually use something like a dijkstra (search it up). Also, while dijkstra's algorithm is awesome, in real life situations, it isn't always practical and as such, most real-life path-finding algorithms are approximations.

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem is ussually *NP complete*, the result might not be guaranteed to be the shortest path, depending of the size of the problem. That said:

If they plan from 1 city to another city via airlines/roads, they probably use a [deterministic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm), such as [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

If they plan a round trip from city to city to city to ... to the home city (which is a *traveling salesman problem*), then they tend to use meta-heuristic algorithms, such as tabu search.